# python having issues with large numbers used as IDs

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am putting together a script to analyze campaigns and report out. I'm building it in python in order to make this easy the next time around. I'm running into issues with the IDs involved in my data, they are essentially really large numbers (no strings, no characters).

when pulling the data in from excel I get floats like this `(7.000000e+16)` when in reality it is an integer like so`(70000000001034570)`. my problem is that im losing a ton of data and all kinds of unique ID's are getting converted to a couple of different floats. I realize this may be an issue with the read_csv function I use to pull these in like this all comes from `.csv`. I am not sure what to do as converting to string gives me the same results as the float only as a string datatype, and converting to int gives me the literal results of the scientific notation `(i.e. 70000000000000000)`. Is there a datatype I can store these as or a method I can use for preserving the data? I will have to merge on the ID's later with data pulled from a query so ideally, I would like to find a datatype that can preserve them. The few lines of code below run but return a handful of rows because of the issue I described.

```
`high_lvl_df = pd.read_csv(r"mycsv.csv")
 full_df = low_lvl_df.merge(right=high_lvl_df, on='fact', how='outer')
 full_df.to_csv(r'fullmycsv.csv')`
```

Comment: read the data in as an integer, don't convert later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may have to do with missing values.

Consider this CSV:

```
70000000001034570,2.                                                               
70000000001034571,3.
```

Then:

```
>>> pandas.read_csv('asdf.csv', header=None)     
                   0    1
0  70000000001034570  2.0
1  70000000001034571  3.0
```

Gives you the expected result.

Hoever with:

```
70000000001034570,2.
,1.                                                                                
70000000001034571,3.
```

You get:

```
>>> pandas.read_csv('asdf.csv', header=None)
              0    1
0  7.000000e+16  2.0
1           NaN  2.0
2  7.000000e+16  3.0
```

That is because integers do not have `NaN` values, whereas floats do have that as a valid value. Pandas, therefore, infers the column type is float, not integer.

You can use `pandas.read_csv()`'s `dtype` parameter to force type string, for example:

```
pandas.read_csv('asdf.csv', header=None, dtype={0: str})                  
                   0    1
0  70000000001034570  2.0
1                NaN  2.0
2  70000000001034571  3.0
```

According to [Pandas' documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

> **dtype** : Type name or dict of column -> type, optional
>
> Data type for data or columns. E.g. {‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32, ‘c’: ‘Int64’} Use str or object together with suitable na_values settings to preserve and not interpret dtype. If converters are specified, they will be applied INSTEAD of dtype conversion.